# How to edit and continue in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, vwdexpress

I've enabled **Enable Edit and Continue** on the Web Properties page and it's also enabled in my configuration, yet Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition refuses to allow me to edit source files of an ASP.NET MVC project. I can edit the aspx file with no problem though.

Any ideas what's wrong or what's missing?

Comment: Now I'm getting another message: Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My conclusion is that it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting x64 or Any CPU on a 64 bit machine you cannot use edit and continue. It only works when you are targeting x32.

I set my Platform target to x32 for the Debug configuration for this reason.

Comment: Interesting point. When I was having the trouble initially I was in a fully 32bit system, so I suppose I was targeting 32bit; but now I'm on 64bit so I'm going to check it out. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember after ticking "Enable Edit and Continue" in your project properties to **Save** your changes before building and testing your app. I made this mistake which cost me more time than I care to share!

[image]

Comment: thanks. Helped a lot was wasting alot of time trying to sort this.

Comment: I definitely had this checked and now it is not... how does this happen.. I know I didn't uncheck it! :<

Answer (score 1):

It works fine at last in Visual Studio 2010 (MVC 4), below are **all required** steps to do it.

I can change e.g. action code in controller (when application is "paused" or stopped at break point) and all changes are automatically used after "Continue" or in step by step debugging.

**Tools > Options > Debuging > Edit and Continue**

[image: Enable Edit and Continue]

**Tools > Options > Debuging > General**

[image: Enable "Brake all..", disable "Require source files..."]

**Build > Configuration Manager...**

[image: Set platform x86 for all projects]

**In Solution Explorer right click on main (web) project name > Properties**

[image: Enable "Edit and continue" for web]

Change build output path to **\bin**

[image: Change build output path to "\bin"]

Source: [Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded](http://sciagaprogramisty.blogspot.com/2012/09/changes-are-not-allowed-if-assembly-has.html)

Comment: +1 for the in-depth answer with screen shots, even though it didn't work for me... ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable this on **two places**.  See this blog post about [Edit and continue for Web Application Projects (WAP)](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevelopertips/archive/2008/11/26/tip-29-did-you-know-how-to-enable-edit-and-continue-feature-for-web-application-projects.aspx)

Comment: I did enable it in two places: Enable Edit and Continue on the Web Properties page and my global Visual Studio configuration. Nevertheless I'll read the post when I get home and see if it adds something I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone running Vista 64 bit...

It may be that the IDE is not ready for Edit and Continue (EnC) web apps on Vista 64 bit without a tweek.

My situation: Migrated Web App to Vista 64 bit. Set platform to x86, set EnC in Tools/Options & Web properties, Debug flag in Web.Config, Debug mode set in Build configuration, etc, etc.

No joy - Could hit break points, inspect variables, etc, but could not EnC.

There were 7 Google hits on Msg "Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded". No new advice there for this situation though.

After trying numerous things finally tried changing the Build output path from "bin\x86\debug" to "bin\".

There was great joy across the land - Debug with EnC works now.