# Edit and Continue not working on Windows 7 , 32 bit OS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

we are using VS 2012 on Windows 7 with 32 bit operating system.

I have enabled "Edit and Continue" feature from Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Edit and Continue.

still I am not able to edit .cs file in debug mode.

can somebody suggest what am I missing?

I kept the break point in one of mvc controller class.
when it hit the break point, I tried to edit and got the below message:

```
Changes are not allowed in the following cases:

  -When the debugger has been attached to an already running process
  -The code being debugged was optimized at build or run time.
  -The assembly being debugged is loaded as domain-neutral.
  -The assembly being debugged was loaded through reflection.
  -When Intellitrace events and call information is enabled.
```

Comment: Check this http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520179/vs2010-sp2-x86-unable-to-edit-and-continue

Comment: but I am using vs 2012

Comment: updated message when tried to edit

Comment: Take help of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927071/713789

Comment: yes it indeed working from unit tests. so the bottom line in we can use this feature in controllers. we can use it from other code files. I was just wondering why I am not able to edit in controller when I have this feature enabled and now it is clear.

Comment: I never use the feature that you describe here. We mostly do manual testing (going through browser) to check our code. You need to compile the project use breakpoints for debug your code. Where do you required Edit and continue ?

Comment: Web Application not support Edit and continue in 2010. Maybe 2012 are same !

Comment: yes.. I came to the same conclusion.Thanks for pointing me to the right question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web application need to be compiled when web-sites is compiled dynamically when executed.

Edit and continue will not work in MVC kind of project. You need to put break point and compile whole project to debug your project.

Comment: I've been able to use Edit and Continue in MVC projects for years. It only stopped working for me when I upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5.2, to Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6.1

Comment: @EastofNowhere At the time of writing that feature doesn't available in VS. Currently, yup it's working.

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify some bits as it might help others..

1) The answer from [Gupta Anirudha F1beta] is correct

These below applies for Visual Studio **2012**, **2013** + **MVC 4**, I was trying to edit **Controller**

2) If *Edit & Continue* is **disabled**, you cannot make changes in the *.cs code, you will see the message as [mmssaann] highlighted above. To edit your code, you need to stop debugging, edit your code and start debugging again to continue

3) If *Edit & Continue* is **enabled**, you can make changes in the *.cs code, BUT you will get a different message after you continue debugging saying **Edit or Restart** (so the website will be recompiled again). This approach is same as above but it seems a bit faster maybe you save like 1 click which makes in 50 years of coding like thousands of saved clicks :-)

I hope this helped :)